# bash: syntax error using (( "$var" == "string" )) for comparisons

Tags: linux, bash

I have this piece of code:

```
if(("$op" == "q")); then
```

which throws out this error:

```
l5p3.sh: line 10: ((: + == q: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "== q")
```

what's the issue? How to compare $op with the letter $q ?

Comment: As a rule, by the way, be more liberal in your spacing when writing shell scripts: `if [ "$op" = "q" ]` will work, whereas `if[$op=q]` will not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(( ... ))` (for arithmetic expressions) is probably not what you want. Check the following:

```
if (("asd" == "bla")); then
  echo test
else
  echo bah
fi
```

It prints `test` in Bash and an error in a strictly bourne-compatible shell like `dash`.

Try the following instead:

```
if [[ $op == q ]]; then
```

Comment: why not (( and )) ? That's how I worked before, with (( and )) and it worked just fine

Comment: @FinalDestiny `((` and `))` are for mathematical operations. You want `[[` and `]]` or `[` and `]` (which are quite different -- and the former is usually better) for comparing strings.

Comment: @NiklasB. `(( $op == q ))` would be actually be dereferencing `$q` and looking for a number there; it's a very different thing from `[[ $op = q ]]`. (Quotes aren't needed on the left-hand side of a `[[` expression, unlike a `[` one, and they're needed on the right-hand side only if that value could be interpreted as a glob pattern).

Comment: @Charles: Yeah, I noticed that. Already deleted that comment (:

Answer (score 1):

For string comparisons you want to use double square brackets not parenthesis. The correct thing to write would be:

```
if [[ "$op" == "q" ]]; then
```

Double parenthesis are used for arithmetic not boolean expressions. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this, spaces between the [] are really important:

```
op="q"
if [ "$op" == "q" ]; then
     echo "hi"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can do like this

```
if test "$op" = "q" ; then
    echo 'hi'
fi
```